# Visual Basic 6.0 disable checkbox on datagrid

Tags: vb6

I have a datagrid table with a text on first column and a checkbox on second column. I would like to disable this checkbox when first column value is "Others". Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set properties for the entire grid.  You can set properties for an entire column.  You can even set a few properties for a cell, but one of those properties is not an enabled property.  The best I was able to come up with was responding to the following event:

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_RowColChange(LastRow As Variant, ByVal LastCol As Integer)
   If DataGrid1.Col = 1 Then
      DataGrid1.Col = DataGrid1.Col - 1

      If DataGrid1.Text = "Others" Then
         DataGrid1.Col = LastCol
         DataGrid1.Row = LastRow - 1
         Exit Sub
      End If

      DataGrid1.Col = DataGrid1.Col + 1
   End If
End Sub
```

This logic prevents focus on a cell in column 2 if column 1 is "Others".  Keep in mind that rows and columns are 0-based.